# How do I force youtube to not use HTML5 in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I have explicitly opted out of the trial:

[image]

However about 10% of videos still play in HTML5.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/405624/how-to-disable-html5-video-on-youtube-with-firefox) question however that tells you how to do it in firefox and not chrome.

Comment: Webapps might give more insight on this from a webapp perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me: join the trial.  Then once joined leave the trial.  Done, back to using Flash on YouTube.

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: It worked for myself so there is obviously something further that is different on your machine.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I asked this question.