# How do I disable videoplayback in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video

I would like to disable video playback in the chrome browser. I have already an answer for flash, by removing the pepperflash plugin, but how do I stop all the other videos.

I tried this solution here, but after creating an automated script to rename the file, I found that the ffmpegsumo.dll does not exist :-(. My version is 45.0.2454.85 (Official Build) m (32-bit).

My reference:
[How to block html5 videos system wide](https://superuser.com/questions/814720/how-to-block-html5-videos-system-wide)

Comment: Do you want to disable autoplay video ?

Comment: @duDE, no, I want to be able to disable video playback, not autoplay, just no play.