# How can I force YouTube to not use HTML5 player because it is not working on the latest version of Firefox and now I can't see any video?

Tags: youtube, flash-player, html5

This is really annoying. Yesterday everything was working fine, now I wake up only to realize that all the videos on YouTube are using the HTML5 player.

[Here](http://s7.postimg.org/nnh7h3tbf/Untitled.png) is what I see when I try to play a video on YouTube:
[image]

I tried what was suggested by the accepted answer [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/405624/how-to-disable-html5-video-on-youtube-with-firefox), but it didn't work, even after restarting Firefox.

Also I would like to note that YouTube works fine in Chrome (HTML5 player) and Internet Explorer (flash player).

Comment: I assume you have Flash installed for Firefox?

Comment: Yes, shockwave flash 17.0.0.134 addon and the flash player from https://get2.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: Firefox sees this plugin as being installed?

Comment: Yes, here are all the plugins.

http://s12.postimg.org/3o2do8ni4/Untitled.jpg

Comment: The greatest thing about this is that it doesn't even work in google chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if the [latest version of Flash is properly installed](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) on your browser. If not, [download the latest version](https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html) and install it.

Then, install the [YouTube Flash Player](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/youtube-flash-player/) extension:

> This add-on forces YouTube to play videos using Flash Player instead of the HTML5 player.

Comment: this worked like a charm, thank you. Still kind of makes me wonder what went wrong with this HTML5 player,but I will accept your answer.

Comment: @jsguy Was the HTML5 player working in Firefox (for YouTube or other sites) before you encountered this issue?

Comment: I am not sure, I never made a check since I was thinking that I was using flash all the time. The first time I heard the term "HTML5 player" was today.

Comment: This worked for me! When i installed firefox i nearly threw the laptop out of the window when youtube didn't work. So i just reinstalled latest version. WORKING :D

Answer (score 5):

You can force YouTube to play a video with flash player by adding **`&nohtml5=1`** or **`&nohtml5=True`** to the URL.

Found this after I had uploaded a video to YouTube and there was "&nohtml5=False" automatically added by any reason.

Comment: In May 2016, this suggestions does not work.

Comment: Thanks for note. If **`True`** does not work use **`1`** instead. Have updated my answer. You may take back "-1" ;)

Comment: I can say that **&nohtml5=1** works, but true does not. This is an answer and should be treaded like it @Criggie ...  +1 from me

Comment: I can confirm that **&nohtml5=1** still works. +1, saved me a bit of frustration.

Comment: This is may 2017 and the nohtml5=1 no longer works neither does nohtml5=true work

Comment: Seems like that youtube has dropped their flash player after all. Since also Google has disabled flash from Chrome 56 on by default.

Comment: I can confirm: nohtml5=1 does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox has release MSE support for HTML5 playback. This uses the system hardware decoders unless the driver is blacklisted. Setting media.windows-media-foundation.use-dxva=false in about:config will use software decoding.

Comment: Going to about:preferences#advanced on the General tab and unchecking "use hardware acceleration when available" should do the same thing. It may require a restart. If that does not work then try Firefox Nightly from https://nightly.mozilla.org/ to check if it is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136484